# Is there an Open source framework based on TCP for multiple client management?

Tags: java, frameworks, tcp, open-source, tcpclient

Is there an open source robust framework available based on TCP for multiple client communication and control via TCP server ?

My goal is to have a TCP client - server established and the framework must have well defined protocol and must be cross platform.

Comment: I wasn't working for a while, so missed checking the thread. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The current cool kid on the block for networking is [Netty](https://netty.io/) which, to quote themselves,

> Netty is a NIO client server framework which enables quick and easy
>   development of network applications such as protocol servers and
>   clients. It greatly simplifies and streamlines network programming
>   such as TCP and UDP socket server.

Most common Netty use cases are HTTP(s) related but as the blurb says, Netty works on lower level than that.

Comment: This looks cool, il try to explore on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Servlet Specification fits your stated requirements about as well as anything possibly can. Well-defined protocol = HTTP and HTTPS, multi platform, multi implementation, *very* widely deployed, ...